# React display logout button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react and session storage to store user data. The reason to use session storage is because on window close, I want the data to be deleted.

The first step I take is to call the API and sent the credentials.

```
const handleLoginForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await axios.post('https://API-web.herokuapp.com/api/login', {email, password});
      if (user.request.status === 200 && user.request.statusText === 'OK') {
       // Stringfy the object and create a 
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.data[0]));
        navigate('/dashboard');
      } 
    } 
    // Catch error block
    catch (error) {
      if (error.response.data === 'Invalid credentials' && error.response.status === 404) 
        return setError(error.response.data);
      else 
        return setError('Something went wrong. Please try again or contact us.');
    }
  }
```

The second step is to create the header and use conditional rendering. If the user is found in the session storage, than display the logout button.
However this is not working unless I refresh the page. Same on login and also on logout.

```
const Header = () => {

  const [isDesktop , setIsDesktop] = useState(true);
  const [user, setuser] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const handleHeader = () => {
    setIsDesktop(!isDesktop);
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    const userObj = await sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    setuser(userObj);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get user from sessionstorage
    getUser();
  }, []);


  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <header>
      
      <p className='logoHeader'>Expense</p>
        <ul className={isDesktop ? 'headerLinks' : 'headerMobile'}>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/dashboard'>Dashboard</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/signup'>Signup</Link></li>

          { user && <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button> }
          { !user && <li><Link to='/login'>Login</Link></li>}
      </ul> 

      <GiHamburgerMenu size={25} color='#333333' className='headerMenu' onClick={handleHeader}/>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: You only appear to be calling `getUser()` on component mount, you will probably need to call it whenever you manually change the session storage as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the `useEffect` in the `Header` component is actually running? I'm assuming that `Header` is a component that is already rendered in the UI while performing the login action. If that is the case, then this method won't work.

Comment: Have you put a `debugger` in your `getUser` function to see if this is being hit, and setting as you'd expect?

Comment: This is because the header never get notified when the session storage get changed. So to change that you could use the context api. The session storage should only be used for app initialization, but not for keeping a dynamic state on runtime, because you will never get the changes unless you call `sessionStorage.getItem`

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was getUser function.
I use the session storage for creating the MVP. 
The solving was this:
  const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));

Answer (score 0):

**Use callback function**

You can achieve this by passing data from child to parent

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [user]);

  const getUser = async () => {
    const currUser = await sessionStorage.getItem("user1");
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(currUser);
    if (jsonObj != null) {
      setUser(jsonObj.userName);
    }
  };

  const handelLogout = async () => {
    await sessionStorage.removeItem("user1");
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box" style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }}>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <h1>Hello {user}!!!</h1>
            <button onClick={handelLogout} className="logout">
              Logout
            </button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <Login getUser={getUser} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


import { useState } from "react";

const Login = ({ getUser }) => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!userName && !password) {
      setError("Please fill all credentials");
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem("user1", JSON.stringify({ userName, password }));
      getUser();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="formBlock">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          value={userName}
          onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        {error && <span>{error}</span>}
        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-xvqzrc)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

### The problem

This is because the header never get notified when the session storage get changed.

This runs only once on app initialization.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get user from sessionstorage
    getUser();
  }, []);
```

So to change that you could use the context api. The session storage should only be used for app initialization, but not for keeping a dynamic state on runtime, because you will never get the changes unless you call `sessionStorage.getItem`

Here the docs of the context api: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

This will help to keep the state reactive in the app.

### The solution

You need to create a context

1. Create a context

```
export const UserContext = createContext([false, () => undefined]);

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   // Get user from sessionstorage
   getUser();
 }, []);

 return (
   <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
     {children}
   </UserContext.Provider>
 );
};
```

2. Bind it to your app

```
<UserContextProvider>
 <App />
</UserContextProvider>
```

3. Then you can use it in your components

```
const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your `getUser` is an async function. You need either `await` it, or do `then`. Or remove the `async`.